# O.O. Teacher List

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, object-oriented

After the feedback I got on my [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/238000/o-o-style-palindrome-checker), I decided to try one more program to see if I understand O.O.P. The idea for this is also based off the project I am working on im my class for this semester which is to make an interactive school tour.

This program just has you make a bunch of teacher instances and then prints them all out.

```py
class Teacher:
    def __init__(self, name, subject, room_number):
        self.name = name
        self.subject = subject
        self.room_number = room_number
    def print_info(self):
        return self.name, self.subject, self.room_number


def instagator(teachers: list) -> list:
    """Creates a version of the teacher class"""
    print("")
    name = input("Please enter a teachers name: ")
    subject = input("Please enter that teachers subject: ")
    room_number = input("Please enter what room that teacher teaches in: ")
    # Makes the varible that holds the instance names after the teacher
    globals()[name] = Teacher(name, subject, room_number)
    teachers.append(globals()[name])
    return teachers


teachers = []
print("Please enter the name of 10 teachers, the subject they teach, and the room they teach that subject in.")
for _ in range(10):
    teachers = instagator(teachers)
print("\n")
for teacher in teachers:
    info = teacher.print_info()
    print(f"{info[0].capitalize()} teaches {info[1]} in room {info[2]}. \n")
```

As with before I just want to know if there is anything wrong with my approach to O.O.P. as I still have very little idea of what I am doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Is the user of your `Teacher` class supposed to be able to modify the `name`, `subject`, and `room_number` attributes after they're set?  If not, make them private by putting a `_` at the start of those names.
2. Python objects have a magic method `__repr__` that turns them into a string for printing.  That would be a good place to put your formatting logic.
3. I don't know what this stuff with `globals` is trying to do, but as a general rule you should not touch `globals`.
4. Your `instagator` function says that it creates a `Teacher`, but it also takes a list of the existing teachers, appends to it, and then returns it.  Try to have your functions do one obvious thing instead of doing multiple non-obvious things.

If your `instagator` function just does the one thing it says it does (creates a `Teacher`), and if you move the string formatting into the `__repr__` function instead of having an intermediate `print_info` that doesn't actually print anything, the code gets a bit simpler:

```
class Teacher:
    def __init__(self, name: str, subject: str, room_number: str):
        self._name = name
        self._subject = subject
        self._room_number = room_number

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self._name.capitalize()} teaches {self._subject} in room {self._room_number}."


def instagator() -> Teacher:
    """Creates a Teacher from user input."""
    print("")
    name = input("Please enter a teachers name: ")
    subject = input("Please enter that teachers subject: ")
    room_number = input("Please enter what room that teacher teaches in: ")
    return Teacher(name, subject, room_number)


print("Please enter the name of 10 teachers, the subject they teach, and the room they teach that subject in.")
teachers = [instagator() for _ in range(10)]
print("\n")

for teacher in teachers:
    print(teacher)
```

Note that since `instagator` returns a `Teacher` I can just use a simple list comprehension to build a list of all the `Teacher`s, one for each number in the `range`.  And since I implemented `__repr__` I don't need to have multiple lines of code to build the string to print; I can just print the `teacher` directly and that will automagically turn into the formatted string that I want.

I don't think it's great practice in general to have a constructor prompt for user input, but for a practice exercise like this I think it's fine to demonstrate how you can use a class to encapsulate all of the logic that pertains to building an object:

```
class Teacher:
    def __init__(self):
        """Creates a Teacher from user input."""
        print("")
        self._name = input("Please enter a teachers name: ")
        self._subject = input("Please enter that teachers subject: ")
        self._room_number = input("Please enter what room that teacher teaches in: ")

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self._name.capitalize()} teaches {self._subject} in room {self._room_number}."


print("Please enter the name of 10 teachers, the subject they teach, and the room they teach that subject in.")
teachers = [Teacher() for _ in range(10)]
print("\n")

for teacher in teachers:
    print(teacher)
```

Comment: The globals() command is to make it so the name of the variable the instance is assigned to is the name of the teacher. I am not entirely sure how it works, but I could not find any better way of doing this.

Comment: You should not do this at all.  There's no need to have named variables for these values at the global scope, especially since you never do anything with those values after you've set them (that's why the purpose was unclear to me).  Global variables in general should be avoided, and defining them dynamically in random places is almost never going to be a good idea.

Comment: You don't want to implement `__repr__`, you want to implement `__str__`.  They are similar, but different.  Roughly speaking: `__repr__` is designed for debugging, and perhaps serialization; `__str__` is for human-readable output.  See [str -vs- repr](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/str-vs-repr-in-python/).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have not gotten this far in your study, but there are actually solutions for this within OOP.

Alternative constructors can be done in Python by [using a `classmethod`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/classmethod-in-python/) (since function overloading is not so easy). Classmethods take as a first argument the class instead of an instance (customarily called `cls` instead of `self`) and return an instance of that class. You can create them by decorating a method with `@classmethod`.

Keeping track of all instances created can be done by having a mutable class attribute which gets updated in the `__init__` method.

In addition I also removed your `print_info` method and added a `__str__` method which prints what you need later, instead. The `__str__` method is called whenever you do `str(x)`, which happens internally also in the `print` function. The `__str__` and `__repr__` methods are similar, but not the same. The former is for when you want a nice human-readable visualization of the instance, and the latter should be a complete representation of the instance, ideally such that `eval(repr(x)) == x`. For more information [read this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/str-vs-repr-in-python/).

```
class Teacher:
    all_teachers = {}

    def __init__(self, name, subject, room_number):
        self.name = name
        self.subject = subject
        self.room_number = room_number
        self.all_teachers[name] = self

    @classmethod
    def from_user(cls):
        """Interactive creation of a teacher."""
        print("")
        name = input("Please enter a teachers name: ")
        subject = input("Please enter that teachers subject: ")
        room_number = input("Please enter what room that teacher teaches in: ")
        return cls(name, subject, room_number)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name.capitalize()} teaches {self.subject} in room {self.room_number}"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Please enter the name of 10 teachers, the subject they teach, and the room they teach that subject in.")
    teachers = [Teacher.from_user() for _ in range(10)]

    for teacher in teachers:
        print(teacher)
        print()
```

The dictionary containing all teachers was not even needed, but you can access it via `Teacher.all_teachers` or `teacher.all_teachers`, where `teacher` is an instance.

Instead I used a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to build a list of teachers.

I also added a [`if __name__ == "__main__":`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/4042267) guard to allow importing from this script without it running.